# JPA/Hibernate Bidirectional Set<Object> on both entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
public class Event {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}

public class User {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How man I make a bi-directional link from User Entity to Event ?

Event entity creates a pivot table called event_users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use @ManyToMany mapping:

```
public class Event {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="events")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}

public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name="event_users",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="event_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I assume the ids of both tables are called `ID` and that the link table contains `user_id` and `event_id`.

User would be the owning side of the relationship here.

Comment: Probably `id` should be specified for both classes.

Comment: well i have assumed that as an obvious thing

Comment: Question, can the ownership be inverse, so that the Event object owns the relationship instead ?